# Redirecting Dynamic URLs with Multiple IDs using .htaccess (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I've just moved my site onto Wordpress, which means the URL structure has now changed. I'd like to use a Rewrite Rule in the .htaccess file to redirect dynamic URLs with multiple IDs in one single statement, but am not having any success. An example is:

OLD URL: example.co.uk/seasons/season.php?ID=1819

NEW URL: example.co.uk/seasons/1819

The statements I have tried in .htaccess are:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/seasons/season.php?ID=(.*).htm$ example.co.uk/seasons/$1
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^?ID=1$
RewriteRule ^/seasons/season.php$ example.co.uk/seasons/? [R=301,L]
```

In neither case, the redirect fires. Is there something about a Wordpress .htaccess file that I'm not considering, or is the error with the statements I'm attempting. I'm using .htaccess 301 redirects for http to https and non-www to www without issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is the fixed version of the approach you chose, to make an external redirection:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)ID=(\d+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?seasons/season\.php$ https://example.co.uk/seasons/$1 [R=301,QSD]
```

Since both, the old and new URLs use the same host name you can simplify that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)ID=(\d+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?seasons/season\.php$ /seasons/$1 [R=301,QSD]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

These rules will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: I will look into placing such rules in the http server host configuration as suggested. For now, I'm testing the rewrite rule – but it has caused an Error 500. I checked the debug file, which says `PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)` – this has me stumped?

Comment: If that really is a current error (does it get repeated when you do a deep reload?) then this means that the rewriting is working as expected. And that you php script is called. But is buggy.

Comment: It does get repeated on a deep reload, yes. I'll investigate the php script.